# Hill cipher with 100x100 matrix?

Tags: cipher, puzzle-creation

Is it possible to decrypt/encrypt something using a Hill Cipher whose key matrix has a size of $100\times100$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Absolutely!

The $n$ x  $n$ matrix $K$ for a Hill cipher can be absolutely  any size for $n$, as long as $K^{-1}$ mod $26$ exists,  and the determinant  mod $26$ has no common factors with $26$.

Furthermore, a larger matrix will make the cipher exponentially more secure. For any matrix used, there are $26^{n^2}$ matrices of $n$ x $n$ that could then be used as the key, and as $n$ increases, the number of possible matrices increases rapidly. This makes it much harder to do any sort of crypt-analysis for larger matrices. (Note that I’m not saying it’s hard to crack, just harder. As it is a linear cipher it can still be cracked relatively quickly using the right script)

For a $100$ x $100$ matrix, there will be $26^{10000}$ possible matrices, which is incredibly large. Although not all of these will be valid matrices, @GregMartin has worked out that about $26$% of them are. If anyone is wondering how large the number actually is, $0.26$ x $26^{10000}$ has over $14000$ digits. Thats a lot of possible matrices.

The problem with larger matrices is it is harder to calculate the determinant, making it harder to make sure the determinant mod $26$ has no common factors with $26$, and to make sure the matrix itself can be inverted.

The largest hill cipher matrix I have ever seen is a $36$ x $36$ matrix, which [dcode](https://www.dcode.fr/hill-cipher) offers an option for.

Overall, yes it is possible, though it will be hard to find a website that supports it. The only things required is that the $100$ x $100$ matrix is invertible, and that the determinant does not have any common factors with $26$.

Put simply, yes if the determinant is non zero, and can't be divided by $2$ or $13$.

Comment: Good answer, but... you should note that there are not $26^{100 \times 100}$ possible keys. Also, the Hill cipher is not secure by any means, it can easily be broken due to linearity. For instance, assume you have $n$ plaintext-ciphertext pairs under the same key, then the key can be trivially computed by solving linear equations.

Comment: @CarlLöndahl I believe there are, each element can have 26 different possibilities and there are 100*100 elements. I’m pretty sure that gives 26^10000. As far the cryptanalysis, I’m definitely not saying larger matrices are hard to crack, but they are most certainly harder than smaller ones. I’ll edit to clarify, I’ll also try to check on the number of keys for nxn.

Comment: Some keys are not possible, since they are not invertible. As an attacker, it would not be meaningful to check singular matrices.

Comment: @CarlLöndahl ahhhh I see what you’re saying. There’s still 26^10000, and I’d say most are valid, but I’ll clarify that a good script wouldn’t check them all

Comment: The percentage of invertible ones is not that high—any matrix with even determinant isn't invertible modulo 26, for example. The exact percentage is a somewhat complicated product that works out to approximately 26.48656%.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks! Even if that is only a quarter, 0.26 * 26^10000 is still very very large :P

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible. There's nothing in the Hill Cipher that requires a specific *size* of matrix -- you just need the matrix to be invertible.